jabref cannot save file while texstudio is running
I add some references into Jabref and try to save the bib file. However, the file cannot be saved. The error message shows that this file is opened by another program. I have checked and confirmed that this is because TexStudio is running. After closing TexStudio, I can save the file.
I want to save file in Jabref while running TexStudio. How can I achieve this?
The version of Jabref is 5.15 and TexStudio is 4.8.3. My O.S. is Windows 11. Thanks.

This is probably still relevant. Anyway, LaTeX should keep the .bib file open only when running bibtex/biblatex, which is just when compiling the file. So probably you should be able to write to the file if the compilation is not running. Switching to manual compilation (and not continuos one, or automatic, or whatever TeXStudio calls it) could help.

I have a question: Do you have the .bib file opened in TeXStudio? For editing? In that case, the lock is perfectly normal and unavoidable (to avoid writing to the file simultaneously and corrupting it).

No. I did not open the .bib file. I just opened my .tex file. Thanks.

This is currently an open issue with the development team. github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/11916

I was having the same problem and tried to debug it. After some research, it turns out that opening a document in TexStudio prevents JabRef from saving any .bib file in the same directory regardless of whether the .bib file is actually used or there are any references to it in the other files in the directory. Hence, it has nothing to do with compliation or TexStudio using the .bib file for autocompletion. I have tried other applications such as Visual Studio Code to edit the .bib file which worked without problems and having the bib file open in Visual Studio Code does not prevent JabRef from saving. Hence, I suggest reporting this issue to the JabRef maintainers.

I created this issue on the JabRef github, https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/11916
